# How can i manage big html hierarchy?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm talking about classes inside classes inside id's inside id's.

I'm finding myself doing this:

```
$("id").children("id").children("class").children("class").
```

and i don't want to use:

```
$("id").find("class")
```

because there are a lot more down the hierarchy.

Is there any sane way to manage it?

Comment: _id's inside id's_ IDs must be unique, So why not `$("id").children("class") ` for immediate children

Comment: Why you don't want to use `.find()` it's actally faster than `.children()`!

Comment: That doesn't sound uncommon. Be carefull though, IDs should be unique, generaly.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, you can chain your selectors too, e.g. `$('#yourID .someNestedClass')`. you can continue this chain as much as required.

Comment: Use `.find()` or `$(selector, context)` if you want to write less.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak find will give me all sub children as well. so i will get inside classes that i didn't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having specific ids for unique items and classes for non-unique elements ***is*** how to manage your hierarchy.

If you think the hierarchy doesn't look neat because of those selectors, it's because you're not chaining the sizzle selectors to a single string.

For your example, you can define the hierarchy in the same selector:

```
$('#id1 #id2 .class1 .class2')
```

Which selects elements that have class2, inside elements that have class1, inside the first element with id=id2, inside the first element with id=id1.
(with those descendant selectors, it helps to read the chain backwards).

Read up on the [descendant-selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and [child-selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and [all of the rest of them](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), to help you select from your hierarchy cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

just use    `$('#element_id').`because id is unique for each element.

Comment: But then i get id names like "asdasd_asdas_fdfd_dfdfdf_Dffdfdf_dfdf". :\

Comment: No you don't, you don't need to concatenate the ids in the hierarchy. If you want to select `id="dfdf"`, then you use `$('#dfdf')`, the # selector selects by id. https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: @sakan is your question about how to build a meaningful hierarchy rather than how to select something already existing in it?

Comment: @StuperUser I know that but i'm saying it for the sake of order, when an other programmer is looking at it he supposed to know what is going on.
I'm building a new system.
This is more a "good or bad practice'" question than technical question actually...

Comment: @sahkan, you learn to visually parse HTML (and the code that builds it) pretty quickly when you're using it everyday and inspect it with good tools.